# Inject custom tag into Microsoft Clarity with GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, ms-clarity

Having user defined variable e.g. `{{username}}`, I want to defined a MS Clarity custom tag

doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/custom-tags

```
clarity("set", "key", "value");
```

Which in GTM context would be:

```
clarity("set", "username", {{username}});
```

#### GTM Clarity custom HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
        c[a]=c[a]||function(){(c[a].q=c[a].q||[]).push(arguments)};
        t=l.createElement(r);t.async=1;t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;
        y=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];y.parentNode.insertBefore(t,y);
    })(window, document, "clarity", "script", "apikey");
</script>
```

#### Question

Where must MS custom tags portion `clarity("set"...` be places in GTM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly refer to the link https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107167?hl=en and below example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       (function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
       c[a]=c[a]||function(){(c[a].q=c[a].q||[]).push(arguments)};
       t=l.createElement(r);t.async=1;t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;
       y=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];y.parentNode.insertBefore(t,y);
       clarity("set", "username", {{username}});
       })(window, document, "clarity", "script", "apikey");
    </script>
```

Comment: "I set this up precisely in GTM, but in the dashboard, under the "Custom Filter" section, I don't see an input filed under the "Custom Tag" section to apply the custom tag that I previously set. What should I do?? @MicrosoftClarity

Comment: Could you please share website address to assist you further.

Comment: yes, this is my website: [basalam.com](https://basalam.com)

Comment: passing number will not work. You need to make it a string.
Not hundred percent sure how the google tag manager works exactly but you can do something like: {{username}}.toString()