# How to set custom ID (user id) in microsoft clarity?

Tags: google-tag-manager, ms-clarity

I want to send a custom user id to Microsoft clarity from GTM and write this in Tag manager.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
        c[a]=c[a]||function(){(c[a].q=c[a].q||[]).push(arguments)};
        t=l.createElement(r);t.async=1;t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;
        y=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];y.parentNode.insertBefore(t,y);
    })(window, document, "clarity", "script", "99999999");
  
    var userId = {{Is Logged In}} ? {{userid}} : 0 ;
    window.clarity("identify", userId)
</script>
```

but when I filter my user id or even 0 in `custom user ID` field in the filter section, it doesn't find anything.

what should I do now?

Comment: Please see this discussion regarding the same:
[Client Side API for GTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66218432/inject-custom-tag-into-microsoft-clarity-with-gtm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some research and make discussion with [clarity account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15155080/microsoft-clarity) finally I found this solution worked:

use `clarity("set")` inside the function.

the point is you should use your custom user id as `string` not `number`!
the final code will be like this:

```
var currentUserId = {{Is Logged In}} ? {{userid}} : '0' ;
(function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
    c[a]=c[a]||function(){(c[a].q=c[a].q||[]).push(arguments)};
    t=l.createElement(r);t.async=1;t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;
    y=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];y.parentNode.insertBefore(t,y);
    clarity("set", "userId", currentUserId.toString());
})(window, document, "clarity", "script", "xxxxx");
```

Comment: What if the user isn't loaded except later?

Comment: remember to set a custom user ID You need the user data, but if you get user data later in GTM you can change the time of initialization of Clarity. it means you can config clarity to init after getting user Data. @Beyondo